# Elastic Beanstalk Passenger-Standalone Rails not serving static assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, passenger, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I use `aws.push` to deploy my rails 4.1 app, it doesn't serve any of my static assets. Everything works but no css, javascript or images.

When I try to run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
Sass::SyntaxError: Invalid CSS after " */": expected "{", was ""
  (in /var/app/current/app/assets/stylesheets/application.css)
(sass):13506
```

My setup is the following:

```
64bit Amazon Linux 2014.03 v1.0.4 running Ruby 2.0 (Passenger Standalone)
Rails 4.1.1
Postgresql
```

Update 1:
Here is my application.css. Its just the default one that comes with rails

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or vendor/assets/stylesheets of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 */
```

I Also forgot one huge thing as well. I get this error in production.log `No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"`

```
F, [2014-07-04T20:25:02.034054 #29628] FATAL -- :
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/stylesheets/application.css"):
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (4.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
  rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
  railties (4.1.1) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
  passenger (4.0.45) lib/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb:74:in `process_request'
  passenger (4.0.45) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:141:in `accept_and_process_next_request'
  passenger (4.0.45) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb:109:in `main_loop'
  passenger (4.0.45) lib/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:448:in `block (3 levels) in start_threads'
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with Passenger or EB, it's all down to the fact that your CSS assets won't compile.

From memory, I think EB will run the rake assets:precompile task when you deploy a new version, if that doesn't work then there will be no assets to serve.

The error you see is indicating that there is an error in your application.css file, can you post the content so we can see what might be wrong?

Comment: Yes Sorry, I added the CSS and the production.log error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh my. It was my own fault. Paul Leader was right it had nothing to do with passenger. The problem was one of my files had some extra characters in another css file: `>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>External Changes`, which was because I used two text editors that conflicted with each other.'

What sucks is that I wish the error didn't say application.css and instead show me the actual file that was causing the problem.

AH!!!!!!!!!